Bus error or Segmentation fault (core dumped) using #pragma omp parallel for
I'm practicing brute force with 2 threads using C++ and OMP library:
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <cstring> 
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 2

int main() {
    unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    std::cout << "Enter hash: ";
    std::string target;
    std::cin >> target; 
    char password[11] = "0000000000";
    bool flag = true;
    std::ostringstream password_stream;
    std::ostringstream hex_hash;
    while (flag) {
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
        for (unsigned long long i = 0; i <= 9999999999ULL; ++i) {
    password_stream <<  std::setfill('0') << std::setw(10)  << i;
        std::string  password_str = password_stream.str();

        MD5(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(password_str.c_str()), password_str.length(), digest);
    
        for (int i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
            #pragma omp critical
            hex_hash << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)digest[i];
        }
        std::string hex_hash_str = hex_hash.str();

    //std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
        if (hex_hash_str == target) {
    #pragma omp critical
            std::cout << "Orginal password: " <<  password_str << std::endl;
            flag = false;
        }

        if (i % 100000 == 0) {
            std::cout << "Wrong: " << password_str << " " << hex_hash_str << " Trying again..." << std::endl;
        }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

But they either trying to write in one stream or I'm getting wrong calculations of hash in hex digit or it's segmentation fault or bus error.
I'm trying to use #pragma omp critical in order to avoid threads writing in one stream. Also I tried to put variables with password and hex-hash of it into global variable before #pragma omp parallel for. All of them result in wrong calculations of hash or segmentation fault.
The password consists of 10 digits

Where does your debugger say it's segfaulting?

It breaks down with two iterations of this for- cycle #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
for (unsigned long long i = 0; i <= 9999999999ULL; ++i) {

Generally, IO operation in a parallel loop is a red flag, especially streaming operations (rarely thread safe). The if(i % 100000 == 0) assume the loops runs serially which is not the case. You cannot track the progression of a parallel loop so easily. A #pragma omp critical in a loop smell a lot : why not locking the whole loop? I expect the locks and IOs to take a signifiant time here, not to mention allocations (possibly caused by std::string tends not to scale).

Does the code produce the correct results [as distinct from taking a longer time] with a single thread (i.e. removing all the #pragmas and running everything sequentially)?

Yes, without threads calculations are right

The purpose of the while loop is unclear. The program would run infinitely, if no match is found or the while loop would run exactly one time. It is also best practice to specify the number of threads using OMP_NUM_THREADS rather than the clause. The following code tries to abort the OpenMP work-sharing loop with cancellation. If cancellation is not supported, the flag will allow to skip the costly part of the loop while finishing the remaining iteration. This builds on @Rob 's solution
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <omp.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Enter hash: ";
  std::string target;
  std::cin >> target;
  std::atomic<bool> flag{false};
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i <= 9999999999ULL; ++i) {
      if (flag)
        continue;
      std::ostringstream password_stream, hex_hash;
      password_stream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(10) << i;
      
      std::string password_str = password_stream.str();

      unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
      MD5(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *>(password_str.c_str()),
          password_str.length(), digest);

      for (int i = 0; i < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++i) {
        hex_hash << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0')
                 << (int)digest[i];
      }
      std::string hex_hash_str = hex_hash.str();

      if (hex_hash_str == target) {
        std::cout << "Orginal password: " << password_str << std::endl;
        flag = true;
        #pragma omp cancel for
        continue;
      }

      if (i % 100000 == 0) {
        std::cout << "Wrong: " << password_str << " " << hex_hash_str
                  << " Trying again..." << std::endl;
      }
    }

  return 0;
}

When compiled with -fsanitize=thread, ThreadSanitizer does not report any data race for this version of the code. TSAN_OPTIONS='ignore_noninstrumented_modules=1' OMP_CANCELLATION=true OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./a.out enables cancellation and sets the number of threads.

I'm getting random errors now...
./md5: line 22: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./md5: line 22: `  typedef decltype(nullptr) nullptr_t;'```
line 16 is ```if (flag)```
line 22 is literally blank line

What command do you execute to get this error?

The output looks like you are trying to execute source code and your shell cannot interpret the c commands. Is ./md5 a text file?

Earlier I compiled C programs and it was ok. I use g++ -o md5.cpp md5 -lscrypto -lssl -fopenmp -fopenmp-simd -fsanitize=thread -E. I define number of threads in the code because it is required by my professor at university. Commands -lscrypto and -lssl are for OpenSSL library, -fopenmp and -fopenmp-simd are for OMP (it doesn’t compile without last command for some reason). -E is for compiling <atomic.h> (it doesn’t compile without it too, and I don’t know why)

Your compiler command has several issues: -E tells the compiler to stop after the preprocessing stage. At this point a text output will be written. -o tells the compiler to write the output to md5.cpp and use md5 as input. What was the compiler error for including atomic? Not <atomic.h>. What is the error for compiling without openmp-simd? What version of g++ do you use?

I tried to compile with g++ md5.cpp -o md5 -lssl -lcrypto -fopenmp and it has compiled only with warning warning: ‘#pragma omp cancel for’ inside ‘nowait’ for construct    37 |         #pragma omp cancel for
I entered hash f1b708bba17f1ce948dc979f4d7092bc (original string "000000000"). And the output was Original password: 0000000000 Wrong: 0000000000 f1b708bba17f1ce948dc979f4d7092bc Trying again... Wrong: 5000000000 86048b5dac10052602bd3294f69937e9 Trying again...
When it waited without output and after a few moments stopped the program

So now there is no mistake with  but the program does not stop after finding the correct password and for some reason outputs two wrong iterations, waits and after few seconds stops. The version of g++ is ```g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0


Cancellation is not guaranteed to happen immediately or at all. It seems like gcc 9 does not implement it. In that case, the program will still need to work through the remaining iterations, but will skip the MD calculations. This can take some seconds. For time measurements, you should add -O3. Regarding the output: the threads might already start execution of an iteration before the flag is set, so they will print that they were executing that loop. With 10^10 iterations, it's very likely that all threads start with an iteration divisible by 100000.

I added a continue to my solution to skip the "wrong result" print out after a solution was found in the current integration.

It now works! Thank you very much!!!

I believe there are a few issues:

password_stream and hex_hash are not thread-safe

std::ostringstream is not thread-safe

Variables flag and password_stream are shared by all threads.

password_stream, hex_hash, and digest are not localized to the threads


Didn't test myself, but try this:
while (flag) {
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NUM_THREADS)
    for (unsigned long long i = 0; i <= 9999999999ULL; ++i) {
        std::ostringstream password_stream;  // moved inside the loop
        password_stream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(10) << i;
        std::string password_str = password_stream.str();

        unsigned char local_digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];  // changed to local
        MD5(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(password_str.c_str()), password_str.length(), local_digest);

        std::ostringstream hex_hash;  // moved inside the loop
        for (int j = 0; j < MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; ++j) {
            hex_hash << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << (int)local_digest[j];
        }
        std::string hex_hash_str = hex_hash.str();

        if (hex_hash_str == target) {
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                std::cout << "Original password: " << password_str << std::endl;
                flag = false;
            }
        }

        if (i % 100000 == 0) {
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                std::cout << "Wrong: " << password_str << " " << hex_hash_str << " Trying again..." << std::endl;
            }
        }

        #pragma omp flush(flag)  // improved
        if (!flag) break;
    }
}


Breaking from an OpenMP work-sharing loop is invalid. You could try to use cancellation, but cancellation is optional. Also, what is the point of the while loop? Why should the next round result in a different result?
